# Jmeter Warning Showing up each time on opening

Tags: jmeter, warnings

I am using Jmeter GUI and upon opening it is showing warning this is what error log shows:2

```
017-04-28 03:44:07,288 INFO o.a.j.g.u.MenuFactory: Skipping org.apache.jmeter.assertions.BSFAssertion
2017-04-28 03:44:10,020 INFO o.a.j.g.u.MenuFactory: Skipping org.apache.jmeter.extractor.BSFPostProcessor
2017-04-28 03:44:10,123 INFO o.a.j.g.u.MenuFactory: Skipping org.apache.jmeter.modifiers.BSFPreProcessor
2017-04-28 03:44:10,221 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/html is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser
2017-04-28 03:44:10,221 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for application/xhtml+xml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser
2017-04-28 03:44:10,221 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for application/xml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser
2017-04-28 03:44:10,221 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/xml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser
2017-04-28 03:44:10,222 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/vnd.wap.wml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.RegexpHTMLParser
2017-04-28 03:44:10,222 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/css is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.CssParser
2017-04-28 03:44:11,571 ERROR o.a.j.e.KeyToolUtils: Exception checking for keytool existence, will return false
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "keytool": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_73]
    at org.apache.jorphan.exec.SystemCommand.run(SystemCommand.java:142) ~[jorphan.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    at org.apache.jorphan.exec.SystemCommand.run(SystemCommand.java:125) ~[jorphan.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    at org.apache.jorphan.exec.KeyToolUtils.checkKeytool(KeyToolUtils.java:436) ~[jorphan.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    at org.apache.jorphan.exec.KeyToolUtils.<clinit>(KeyToolUtils.java:94) ~[jorphan.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.ProxyControl.<clinit>(ProxyControl.java:248) ~[ApacheJMeter_http.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.gui.ProxyControlGui.createPortPanel(ProxyControlGui.java:708) ~[ApacheJMeter_http.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.gui.ProxyControlGui.init(ProxyControlGui.java:664) ~[ApacheJMeter_http.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.gui.ProxyControlGui.<init>(ProxyControlGui.java:239) ~[ApacheJMeter_http.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_73]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_73]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_73]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_73]
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_73]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.util.MenuFactory.initializeMenus(MenuFactory.java:505) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.util.MenuFactory.<clinit>(MenuFactory.java:169) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.gui.TestPlanGui.createPopupMenu(TestPlanGui.java:93) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.tree.JMeterTreeNode.createPopupMenu(JMeterTreeNode.java:156) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.EditCommand.doAction(EditCommand.java:46) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.performAction(ActionRouter.java:74) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.lambda$actionPerformed$0(ActionRouter.java:59) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_73]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_73]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_73]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_73]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_73]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_73]
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_73]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_73]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_73]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_73]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_73]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_73]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_73]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_73]
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_73]
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_73]
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_73]
    ... 35 more
2017-04-28 03:44:14,937 INFO o.a.j.e.KeyToolUtils: keytool found at 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_73\bin\keytool'
2017-04-28 03:44:14,938 INFO o.a.j.p.h.p.ProxyControl: HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder SSL Proxy will use keys that support embedded 3rd party resources in file D:\Jmeter\apache-jmeter-3.2\bin\proxyserver.jks
2017-04-28 03:44:15,997 INFO o.a.j.g.u.MenuFactory: Skipping org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.BSFSampler
2017-04-28 03:44:16,117 INFO o.a.j.s.FileServer: Default base='D:\Jmeter\apache-jmeter-3.2\bin'
2017-04-28 03:44:16,852 INFO o.a.j.g.u.MenuFactory: Skipping org.apache.jmeter.protocol.mongodb.config.MongoSourceElement
2017-04-28 03:44:16,854 INFO o.a.j.g.u.MenuFactory: Skipping org.apache.jmeter.protocol.mongodb.sampler.MongoScriptSampler
2017-04-28 03:44:20,136 INFO o.a.j.g.u.MenuFactory: Skipping org.apache.jmeter.timers.BSFTimer
2017-04-28 03:44:20,265 INFO o.a.j.g.u.MenuFactory: Skipping org.apache.jmeter.visualizers.BSFListener
2017-04-28 03:44:20,922 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleResult: Note: Sample TimeStamps are START times
2017-04-28 03:44:20,923 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleResult: sampleresult.default.encoding is set to ISO-8859-1
2017-04-28 03:44:20,923 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleResult: sampleresult.useNanoTime=true
2017-04-28 03:44:20,924 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleResult: sampleresult.nanoThreadSleep=5000
```

Note:I tried running it with administrator but it was of no use.Also on using constant timer status is always shows warning signs for each sample.Much thanks in advance for guidance.

Answer (score 4):

The error you are getting indicates that JMeter cannot find [keytool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/keytool.html) utility which is a part of Java Runtime Environment or Development Kit.

However if you look into the next line after the error:

> 2017-04-28 03:44:14,937 INFO o.a.j.e.KeyToolUtils: **keytool found at** 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_73\bin\keytool'

so you can ignore this warning (or report it via [JMeter bugzilla](http://jmeter.apache.org/issues.html)) so developers could take a look into it.

---

In the meantime I would recommend the following workaround:

1. Uninstall your `jre1.8.0_73` (it is old in any case)
2. Download latest version of 64-bit Server JRE or JDK from [Oracle website](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index-jsp-138363.html)
3. Install it to the folder which doesn't contain spaces or non-ASCII characters, i.e. to `C:\java`
4. Add the next 2 lines to beginning of `jmeter.bat` startup script:

   ```
   set JAVA_HOME=c:\java
   set PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH%
   ```

It should give JMeter a "good" Java configuration and the issue should go away.

See [How to Get Started With JMeter: Part 1 - Installation & Test Plans](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-get-started-jmeter-part-1-installation-test-plans) article for proper steps on installing and starting using JMeter

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, you may experience the failure of expanding the environment variable **PATH**, like:

```
C:\>echo %PATH%
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;C:\Windows\System32;
```

Notice the literal value **%JAVA_HOME%\bin**. This is caused by:

1. 'PATH' contains reference of other variable
2. 'PATH' is modified without evaluation (e.g. by program)

**Solution**

1. Open the environment setting box
2. Do some modification of the value of PATH (trigger the expansion of variables)

This should fix the problem. We can now open a ***new*** cmd window and check the value of PATH.

```
C:\>echo %PATH%
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin;C:\Windows\System32;
```

Note that the value **%JAVA_HOME%\bin** has been expanded to **C:\java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin**.